# How to read token/property from file to use in liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

Is there a way to read token/property from file to use in liquibase?

Ex: I'm having a version stored in properties file & i wants to get this version from that file & wants to insert it into table via liquibase. How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Satish Lakhani

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameters in the changelog (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) and pass property file as a parameter (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html - see "optional parameters" section).